# Is $Tr[AuBv]=uBv Tr[A]$ true?

Tags: matrices

Let $A=[A]_{n\times n}$, $B=[B]_{m\times m}$, $u=[u]_{1\times m}$ and $v=[v]_{m \times 1}$. Since $uBv$ is just a *number*, can we say that

$$Tr[AuBv]=uBv~ Tr[A]~?$$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are correct. This is a [property of the trace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_(linear_algebra)#Properties)

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely, trace is linear! :)